# Hourly files from 2AM to next day 2 AM as input to Pig

Tags: regex, shell, apache-pig, oozie

We have a requirement where we are receiving hourly files daily. So in a day we receive 24 files. We have a pig action for which these files will be the input. Now only the files from present day 2 AM to next day 2 AM should be the input to the pig action. This job should be automated for future as well. The rest of the files will be input to another pig action.

File format : abcdef_20170810-020000.tar.gz (02 represents 2AM file) Hours will be in 24 hr format.

So the input for pig action should be files from  abcdef_20170810-020000.tar.gz to  abcdef_20170811-020000.tar.gz

Is there any way in shell script that this can be achieved? The pig action is a part of the oozie workflow.

I tried with many regular expression but since the file format is not very much unique I am not able to crack this down.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want the 2am file to be processed both yesterday and today?

Comment: no.... It should be 2 AM to next day 1 AM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) tag, how about

```
today=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
yesterday=$(date -d yesterday "+%Y%m%d")
cd /location/of/daily/files
files=( 
    abcdef_${today}-0[012]0000.tar.gz
    abcdef_${yesterday}-0[2-9]0000.tar.gz
    abcdef_${yesterday}-1[0-9]0000.tar.gz
    abcdef_${yesterday}-2[0-3]0000.tar.gz
)
do_something_with "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: If shell is not an appropriate language, it should be straightforward to translate to your language of choice.